# Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted [magic]

Tags: javascript, next.js, magic-sdk

When using the `magic-sdk` v8.0.1 I am getting this warning:

```
warn  - ./node_modules/magic-sdk/dist/es/index.js
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
```

Can someone tell me what is happening here?

Comment: Are you using TypeScript by any chance?

Comment: @juliomalves no

Comment: @Matt are you getting this on a Moralis project?

Comment: @RoyBarber I am getting this on Moralis project

Comment: @Matt, I have the same issue, did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to the magic-sdk's ESM output. You can ignore this warning because it is not considered a bug or make your bundler config to resolve `magic-sdk` to its CommonJS entrypoint (`magic-sdk/dist/cjs/index.js`).

A detailed explanation could be found here: https://github.com/magiclabs/magic-js/issues/295